How to split out this multi table transaction CRUD operations?
I currently have a process that is doing the following:
START TRANSACTION  
DELETE FROM Foo WHERE id=123;  #id is PK
DELETE FROM Bar WHERE foo_id=123; #multirow delete  
INSERT INTO FooBar the row we deleted application level logic  
END TRANSACTION

I want to find a way to not dot it all at one blocking transaction. I was thinking to add cols to indicate if a row has been deleted and run another process for cleanup but I was wondering if there is another way that perhaps MySQL supports

You could maybe do the deletes together, if there's a foreign key constraint in Bar referencing Foo and you can define the foreign key to perform cascading deletes. But that still requires locks, and anyway it won't perform the insert. I think you do need a transaction.

@BillKarwin:What if I reversed the operations? Do 1 update with a column that marks the rows as inactive in Foo and the do the inserts, the bulk delete and the delete by PK in this order? So if any step in this breaks I still will be able to recover. Would that have any pitfalls?

I'm still not sure what problem are you trying to solve with these steps. If you use a transaction, and one of the steps fails, you can either retry that one step, or else rollback the transaction and start over all the steps.

@BillKarwin:The table Foo is heavily accessed for updates and that first DELETE holds locks to many rows till it finishes the bulk DELETE/INSERT and there is lots of contention between other operations. I was thinking about the split I mentioned as a way to improve this contention

The updates you suppose to use will also create locks on the same rows.

@BillKarwin: yes but this snippet in the post will hold the locks for quite a while though while the others will be simple row updates

Okay, then do the INSERT first, as you say, then do the DELETEs. If anything goes wrong with the DELETE's, then you can rollback the whole transaction, which includes the INSERT.
